# Are Window's SIDs in AD case-sensitive?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003

Are [Security Identifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc230371.aspx) in AD case-sensitive? How I can check this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the [same link you've provided](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc230371.aspx) in your question:

> The formal string syntax is given in section [2.4.2.1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff632068.aspx).

Alright, let's follow that link and read that page (emphasis, mine):

> The SID string format syntax, a format commonly used for a string representation of the SID type (as specified in section 2.4.2), **is described by the following ABNF syntax**, as specified in [[RFC5234]](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5234.txt).

Sounds good, click another link... some more reading...

> NOTE:
>
> ```
>  ABNF strings are case insensitive and the character set for these
>   strings is US-ASCII.
> ```

Comment: You just put my answer to shame :D nice deduction

Answer (score 2):

A Windows SID structure always begins with `S-1` - an uppercase S, a dash, and a 1 - denoting the data type and revision (always 1).

So yes, the SID structure is case-sensitive; **BUT** SID consumers, like Windows itself for example, does not treat SID's with case-sensitivity

Answer (score 2):

A SID is a [variable length binary structure](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc962011.aspx). The "standardized notation" for representing it as a string does seem to have a capital S but it really depends on what is parsing the string and whether it will care if the S is capital or not.

That ANBF format isn't 100% accurate: it specifies that sub-authorities can be represented as a 10 digit integer, but 99999 99999 (max value for 10 digits) is outside the range of a `ULONG`, which is a 32-bit integer. The actual maximum value is 2^32=4294967296.